# Fragment transition from specific UI point(enlarge image to full screen)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a fragment with image thumbnails. On click of a thumbail, a new fragment with full screen image is loaded.I am using the below code to animate the full screen image fragment. The problem is animation always starts from the center of the screen.Is there any way by which I can load the new fragment from clicked image thumbnail position?

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@integer/scale_anim_dur"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@integer/scale_anim_dur"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0" />

</set>
```